# Paypal One Page Store ASP.net MVC download file

Tags: paypal, online-store

I need to create a very simple store to sell an excel 2013 Add in with paypal paiment system.
When the payment is OK, the user is allowed to download file.
Is it possible ?
Regards,
Laurent

Answer (score 0):

Sure , i'ts possible ! for security reason i suggest you to avoid a simple redirect to the download page after the payment.

There are some services called "auto buy" try to check it out on google!